# How to make Xcode Simulator show up in the same window as Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I am using Xcode 7.1, and when I run the simulator, it opens in a different window. This makes it hard to see changes in Xcode while viewing the simulator. Is there a way to make the simulator appear on the same window as Xcode?

Comment: Please show some example screenshots

Comment: no idea what you are asking

Comment: do you want the simulator window to placed somewhere or do you want the app to start in a particular window/view?

Comment: You can't doc the simulator, but you can change the size and position of the windows of both apps. Usually you just want the simulator in front till you hit a breakpoint and then Xcode will move forwards...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you run Xcode in full screen mode. If you run Xcode in non full screen mode both applications (Xcode and iOS simulator) will bee on the same page.

Answer (score 5):

Required Xcode 9.3 and above
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YFPUgQpUmuE

copy and paste the command below to the terminal

```
defaults write com.apple.iphonesimulator AllowFullscreenMode -bool YES
```

then hit enter to execute and reopen the iPhone simulator.

Answer (score 1):

I found another approach to this as I wasn't running Xcode in fullscreen mode yet the simulator was still opening on another desktop on my mac (per the solution above). I solved this by:

1. Starting the simulator (it opens on another desktop)
2. Going back to the screen I want the simulator to open in (the same as my Xcode in my case)
3. Right-click the simulator icon
4. Select Options/Assign To/This Desktop